# 100kg of berries are 99% moisture, by weight. After two days, 98% moisture. What was their total weight after two days?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> In a store window, there was a flat containing boxes of berries having a total weight of 100 kg. An analysis showed that the berries were 99% moisture, by weight. After two days in the sun, a second analysis showed that the moisture content of the berries was only 98%, by weight. What was the total weight of the berries after two days, in kg?

Did any of you get 50kg because I got something like 98kg and I'm totally wrong?  :(

Comment: It is 50 kg. How did you get 98?

Comment: This is sometimes known as the Potato Psradox. You have to think about the non-water part of the berries, which doesn't lose weight, and what it's $1\%$ or $2\%$ of.

Answer (score 5):

You have to think about the non-water content, not the water.

Initially, the berries are $1\%$ solids, and all the rest is water.

After drying out, they're $2\%$ solids, and all the rest is water.

The solids haven't changed weight. So if they've gone from being $1\%$ to $2\%$ of the total weight, the total weight must have halved.

The thing with this one, known as the [Potato Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potato_paradox), is that it feels intuitively wrong even after carefully working it out and getting the right answer. Instinctively we feel the water has gone down to $\frac{98}{99}$ of what it was, but instinct turns out to be wrong.

I think it's because we're used to comparing percentages of some fixed total amount, while here the total amount is what changes.

Answer (score -1):

Name the dry weight $d$, the water (moisture) $w$, and total mass $m=d+w$.

The first amount of moisture $w_1$, the second amount (after two days) $w_2$, the first relative moisture content $r_1 = \frac{w_1}{d+w_1}$, and the second relative moisture content $r_2 = \frac{w_2}{d+w_2}$.

Then at the start you have $m_1 = d+w_1 = 100$ kg and $r_1 = 0.99$, and after 2 days you have $r_2 = \frac{w_2}{d+w_2} = 0.98$ and want to know $d+w_2$.

As $r_1 = \frac{w_1}{m_1}$ it follows that $w_1 = r_1 m_1$ and therefore the dry weight $d = m_1 - w_1 = m_1 - r_1 m_1 = (1-r_1)m_1 $.

After two days $r_2 = \frac{w_2}{d+w_2}$ or $ w_2 = r_2 (d+w_2)$ or $(1-r_2)w_2 = r_2 d$ or $w_2 = \frac{r_2}{1-r_2}d = r_2 \frac{1-r_1}{1-r_2}m_1$ and $ m_2 = d+w_2 = (1-r_1)m_1 + r_2 \frac{1-r_1}{1-r_2}m_1 = (1-r_1) \left(1+\frac{r_2}{1-r_2}\right)m_1 = \frac{1-r_1}{1-r_2}m_1$.

Therefore $m_2 = \frac{1-0.99}{1-0.98}100$ kg $= 50$ kg.

Comment: This is incredibly convoluted. Just notice that $d = 0.01m_1 = 0.02m_2$ so $m_1 = 2m_2$

Comment: In this specific case, yes. I tried to approach it formally for the general case, also for my later reference.

Comment: @Zanzag For instance, a mushroom grower uses 4 kg wheat straw of 13% relative moisture content, but needs 55% relative moisture content in order for the mushrooms to grow. How much water does he have to add?
We know the new w2 = r2(d+w2) -> w2 = r2.d/(1-r2) 
and w1 = r1(d+w1) -> w1 = r1.d/(1-r1) so the amount of water to add w2-w1 = d[r2/(1-r2) - r1/(1-r1)] 
We know w1 = r1(d+w1) = 0.13*4 = 0.52 kg, therefore d = 4-0.52 = 3.48 kg.
Now w2-w1 = 3.48*(0.55/0.45 - 0.13/0.87) = 3.7333 kg water to be added. 
How 'incredibly convoluted' is that?

Comment: Again, just notice $d = 0.87m_1 = .45m_2$ so $d = 3.48$ and you will need a total volume of $3.48/.55 = 4.25$ liters. Since you already have $.13 * 4 = 0.45$ liters, you need to add $3.73$. You can't really believe your method is simpler, you are conflating formality with unnecessary notation. You can see that the other answer to the OP is way simpler.

Comment: 1. I never said my method was simpler.

2. Thanks for showing your general way of solving this, indeed it's really fast and direct.

3. I maintain there's a difference between fast and formal.

4. You might have used kg instead of liters.